# Extract word or character after matched string excluding whiteSpace and matched string using regex

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

"1 cup of Greek or natural yoghurt."

I want cup to be filtered out.

"1gm of salt."

Here i want gm to be extracted.

I want a regex expression which is the combination of both.

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: What regex have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
/^(.+?)( cup|gm)(.+?)$/i
```

replace to

```
\1 \3
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yJ1sS2/1)